# .env variable file is not working on visual studios

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, variables, environment-variables

Hi I'm using Visual Studios and .env is not working for me ?

I'm not sure what is up.

The project is using an express backed and React Front end. 
[image: Folder Directory]

REACT_APP_KEY = "Test"

```
console.log(1);
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY);
console.log(2);
```

Result 
[image: Console Result]

Requested Code

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());

// Upload Endpoint
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  if (req.files === null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }

  const file = req.files.file;

  file.mv(`${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/${file.name}`, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}` });
  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server Started...'));
```

Note that I am calling .env from React front end

Comment: try using "dotenv" npm package for loading the env files

Comment: @HS I tried npm Install dotenv but that's it

Comment: you will have to use it too - using the config method - check usage here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 0):

You should declare this variable before running `npm start`.

In your case it will be

`REACT_APP_KEY="TEST" npm start`

I would suggest creating a .env file and using the dotenv package to load environment variables.

Comment: I'm using concurrently to run client and server at the sametime ?Could that be the problem ?

Comment: no thats not the problem. Can you post server.js file code?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was install dotenv inside the create-react-app "client" folder
and configure dotenv before mounting my component

Thanks All,

Inside React App Component

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
```